# How to create redirect through an intermediate page on subdomain

Tags: php, redirect

How to do url redirection through a subdomain for outbound links which are on a homepage? 
The link structure I want to achieve is below. Say a user go on homepage clicks on a link then this happens:

outbound link ---> intermediate page on subdomain---> external site

```
https://go.homepage.com/go/externalsite.com
```

Thanks

Comment: this will do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @netzding I saw that before posting, that is about page redirect. My question is about url redirect on page.

Comment: but you can pass any url to the header() function so whats the problem ? well you have the url as a get parameter... so fetch it and use it for header()

Comment: @netzding there are several urls on the page coming from feeds.

Comment: make a mysql server with link ids like www.google.com with ID 15 and https://go.yoursite.com?refid=15, in index.php of go.yoursite.com grabs the refid using $_GET command and matches in mysql and sends to google.com. The advantage of this would be you could track user activity.